# How to call a perl cgi script from another perl cgi script

Tags: html, perl, templates

I have a html form ... While submitting that form, I am calling one Perl CGI Script, that will save the data in MYSQL database.

After saving the data in databse, i want to reopen the same page with all empty fields in form, means i want too reload the same form again.

How can i achieve this? or what should i call in my script so that i can come back to same form again.

Remember i am generating the forms using template and perl script..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect using HTML's [`meta refresh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) or by using JavaScript's `window.location` object. Have the CGI script output any of those.

Another way is to have the CGI script output a redirect header. You can use [`CGI`](http://metacpan.org/module/CGI)'s [`redirect`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER) method for this, or output it manually.

Comment: I am using the following to  redirect the page to another url. Its not redirecting the page.. infact its printing **http://localhost/cgi-bin/newClientForm.cgi** . i mean uRL on a new html page.

my $url = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/newClientForm.cgi";
print "Location: $url\n\n";

what is wrong in this??
please help

Thanks

Comment: That is because the script already outputs a `Content-type: text/html\n\n` header earlier in the script. For redirection to work, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this second program really a CGI program? I mean does it accept parameters from a HTTP request and return it's results in an HTTP response?

If that's the case then you can call it using libraries from the [LWP](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) CPAN distribution.

If your second program is actually just a command program then you can call it using [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Comment: I am using the following to  redirect the page to another url. Its not redirecting the page.. infact its printing **http://localhost/cgi-bin/newClientForm.cgi** . i mean uRL on a new html page.

my $url = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/newClientForm.cgi";
print "Location: $url\n\n";

what is wrong in this??
please help

Thanks